# Approximating/ Slacking up measurable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ are two bounded real-valued measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose $f_1(x,y) \geq f_2(x,y) \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Can we write $f_1(x,y) = g(x) + f_2(x,y)$?, where $g(x)$ is some bounded real-valued measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, can a single variable function make up for the slack.?

If not how to define closeness and approximate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally not.  This requires that $f_2(x,y)-f_1(x,y)$ be a function of $x$ only.  As an example, let $f_1(x,y)=0, f_2(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$.  Because $f_2$ depends on $y$ you can't.

Comment: I see. How would one define closeness with measurable functions?

Comment: You can certainly define $g(x,y)$ as the difference of your two $f$'s and use the integral of $g$ as the distance.